# automorphism group of the disc $\mathbb{D}-\{p,q\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, automorphism-group, mobius-transformation

The automorphism group of the punctured disc $A=\mathbb{D}-\{a\}$ consists of all holomorphic maps $f$ from $A$ onto itself, and since $A$ is bounded, then $f$ should be bounded, and so $a$ is removable singularity and hence $f$ extends to the automorphism on $\mathbb{D}$ .

Can I extend this argument to the punctured disc $B=\mathbb{D}-\{a,b\}$? with two isolated singularities $a, b$.

Comment: So, we can, right? if so, we can extend it to $\mathbb{D}-A$ where $A$ a set of finite number of distinct points in $\mathbb{D}$, right?

Comment: the problem is that if $f$ automorphism, then one must have $f(a)=a$ which limits the number of potential automorphisms; for more than a point, only the identity works as a (nontrivial) disc automorphism can have at most one fixed point inside the disc (or two on the boundary); more generally a (nonidentity) holomorphic self map of the unit disc cannot have more than one fixed point by Schwarz Pick